# Wordpress Admin Menu defining function is seperate file

Tags: plugins, admin, admin-menu

Here is my current code,

*aio_menu.php*

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No script kiddies please!' );
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'AIO_menu_creator' );
function AIO_menu_creator() {

    add_menu_page( 'AIO WooCommerce Plugin', 'AIO', 'manage_options', 'aio-dashboard', plugins_url('AIO-WooCommerce-Plugin/menu/aio_dashboard.php'), plugins_url('AIO-WooCommerce-Plugin/ico.png') , '81.912514514511451' ); 
}
require_once 'aio_dashboard.php';

?>
```

*aio_dashboard.php*

```
<?php

function my_plugin_options() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
        wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
    }
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    echo '<p>Here is where the form would go if I actually had options.</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}

add_action( 'current_screen', 'my_plugin_options' );

?>
```

[image: the image of the page]

in my main plugin file,

`require_once 'menu/aio_menu.php';`

I want to add sub menu items like, dashboard, shipping editor, price specifier and etc.

So, aio_menu will have all my menu's specified and I will have aio_dashboard and so on for the page content.

Now I want to align the content I get in the middle of the page and make sure the notifications which are shown are properly shown. I know I am doing something wrong in aio_dashboard file.

Can anyone just suggest me how to get the content I want in the page correctly?Just this,

> a h3 title DASHBOARD

and below it

> 'content goes here'

It should be in the admin page.

Here is an example of where I want my content,
[image]

I have edited it with inspect element. You can compare the first image and second so any ideas how to get it in the correct place ?

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Unfortunately your question is way too broad. What you are asking is for someone to code the entire project for you, and that will in all probability not happen. Please break your question up into a couple smaller ones, and most importantly, post your code, working or not and explain where you are stuck and the exact problem you are experiencing. Thank you :-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen :) I did it. Just want the content in middle. Found out how to add submenu to custom top level menus :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$function` argument of `add_menu_page` should be a function that produces your page output, or if omitted, then the `$menu_slug` argument can be a file that when included will output the menu page.

But your output right now has nothing to do with the `add_menu_page` call, the problem is that you're requiring `aio_dashboard.php`, which has a function hooked to `current_screen`. The `current_screen` action should not generate output, that's not what it's for, it fires too early in the load process. Its purpose is for adding filters and actions based on the current admin page being viewed.

Change the `add_menu_page` `$function` argument to contain the function that outputs the page content, remove the `add_action` call hooking that function to `current_screen`.

Comment: So i wouldn't be needing aio_menu.php ? and is adding this in aio_dashboard.php enough ?
`add_menu_page( 'AIO WooCommerce Plugin', 'AIO', 'manage_options', 'aio-dashboard', 'my_function'), plugins_url('AIO-WooCommerce-Plugin/ico.png') , '81.912514514511451' ); `
and `add_submenu_page( 'aio-dashboard', 'AIO WooCommerce Plugin', 'Dashboard', 'manage_options', 'my_function');`

I will add this in aio_dashboard.php and for the next submenu defining the `add_submenu_page` is enough in the next .php file I hope. anyway to manage all menu creation in aio_menu.php and only functions in other files ?

Comment: Sorry stupid of me asking the question :P I just needed to add the function name instead of the file location and make sure its required once and it works :D http://gyazo.com/2a200d9a756689f2e119617db9e60744

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wants to add their own admin menu ;) The format is,

`<?php
add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position );
?>`

`<?php add_submenu_page( $parent_slug, $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function ); ?>`

(from wordpress codex)

```
<?php
    defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No script kiddies please!' );
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'mgg_aio_menu_creator' );
    function mgg_aio_menu_creator() {

        add_menu_page( 'AIO WooCommerce Plugin', 'AIO', 'manage_options', 'aio-dashboard', 'mgg_aio_dashboard', plugins_url('AIO-WooCommerce-Plugin/ico.png') , '81.912514514511451' ); 
        add_submenu_page( 'aio-dashboard', 'AIO WooCommerce Plugin', 'Dashboard', 'manage_options', 'aio-dashboard', 'mgg_aio_dashboard');
        add_submenu_page( 'aio-dashboard', 'Shipping Options | AIO WooCommerce Plugin', 'Shipping Options', 'manage_options', 'aio-shipping-options', 'mgg_aio_shipping_options');
    }
    require_once 'aio_dashboard.php';
    require_once 'aio_shipping_options.php';
    ?>
```

You will have a menu like this,
[image]